# Does the a.out file contain instruction sets for the perticular processor?

Tags: c++

I am new to programming in C++ and I was just curious as to what is actually in the .out file after we compile our code for example with gcc?

Does it contain instruction set for the particular processor that the program is running on? or is it a series of 0s and 1s?

Thank you for the help!

Comment: Yes, it contains instructions for the target architecture. Yes, it is a series of 0s and 1s (like everything on a computer).

Answer (score 1):

An executable file in its main body (such files usually have 'header' with meta-information and main body) contains 0s and 1s only. These bits encode instructions for the target platform (processor) and data (if you don't use cross-compilation the instruction set if for your own processor).

You may read an executable file with a HEX editor (stand-alone one, hex extension for VS Code, etc.). It shows 'opcodes'. A list of opcodes can be found in processor developer specifications and docs. Example of opcode for x86 platform can be found [here](http://ref.x86asm.net/coder64.html).

[Opcodes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l5WQj.png)

On the image above I have selected the first meaningful opcode in my executable file. It means "push the eBP processor register on stack". Check the table [here](http://sparksandflames.com/files/x86InstructionChart.html).

Summary:

1. In general, an executable file contains 0s ans 1s
2. These 0s and 1s can be read as HEX opcodes
3. You can find descriptions of these opcodes and corresponding processor instructions descriptions in specs or just in the internet